# php mail function sending multiple emails

Tags: php, email

I am trying to implement the simple email function with php mail. Code is as follows

```
    $headers = 'From: "From Display Name" <sender@sender.dom>' . PHP_EOL .
       'Cc: "CC Display Name" <copied@copied.dom>' . PHP_EOL .
       'X-Mailer: PHP-' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
   if(mail('test@test.com', 'test', 'test message', $headers, 'test@test.com')) echo "sent";
   else "not sent";
```

But problem is this code is sending the same email 6 times, and i can not figureout why... any ideas?
The "Sent is echoed only one time though!!!"

Complete CODE:

```
if($_POST['submitted']=="1"){
$error = "";

if($error==""){

    $headers = 'From: "From Display Name" <sender@sender.dom>' . PHP_EOL .
       'Cc: "CC Display Name" <copied@copied.dom>' . PHP_EOL .
       'X-Mailer: PHP-' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
   if(mail('test@test.com', 'test', 'test message', $headers, 'test@test.com')) echo "sent";
   else "not sent";

}
```

}

Comment: isn't it wrapped up by some for/while loop ?

Comment: From the code you have posted, there is no reason this would be sent more than once. You should post the entire code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by using the email address as the 5th parameter to the mail function?

Comment: It isnt wrapped in any loop; 4th parameter is returnpath.

Comment: I updated the question.. I meant 5th..

Comment: shouldn't that be the sender email? and also with a -f in front?

Comment: I ran this code only replacing the email addresses and it sent just one email and one copy.. so maybe the problem is in some other place

Comment: yes, when i run the same code is test php file, it sends only one email. But when i include the file in my template to show menulines..... its sending 6 emails.

Comment: Don't use `PHP_EOL` in your email headers. RFC 2822 specifies that the EOL character in email headers must be CRLF (ie: "\r\n").

Comment: ...and what is the code for your `template to show menulines`? Seems like you are probably calling `include()` within a loop that is iterating 6 times...

Comment: On a side note: Why not stop using the mail() function directly and use a wrapper instead, like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)?

Comment: I tried PHPmailer, unfortunately same results. Insted of sending one email... its sending 6 emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is the reason: For validation and "!!|-: SECURITY :-|!!" checks, that template is getting called 6 times before Showing the results in browser!!!!!!!!!!